# Saving user input as an option into code - Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm coding my first Chrome extension. Now I want to save user input (API key) as option into the code, so the code runs with this input.

I have a file `background.js`, which runs my `code.js` with

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "code.js"})
});
```

I have the file `code.js`, looking like:

```
(function(){var win=window.open('https://my-test-tool.com?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href )+'&k=<API-KEY>','_blank');win.focus();})()
```

And i have the file `options.html` with the form to input the API key, like

```
<label>
Input API Key
<input type="text" id="wptk">
</label>
<button id="save" onclick="save_options()">Save</button>
<div id="status"></div>
<script src="options.js"></script>
```

Further i have `option.js` with following code:

```
function save_options() {
  var api = document.getElementById('wptk').value;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
    savedApi: api,
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);
  });
}

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save_options);
```

All of them are already in the `manifest.json`, `storage` too.

**I'm on this point now**: after installing an extension i open options from extension toolbar, input a string into the input field, and after pressing <kbd>save</kbd> i see triggered `Option saved` message.

**Question**: how could i put the user input, which i saved in the options into the `code.js`, after `&k=` instead of placeholder `<API-KEY>`.

**Example**: if user inputs `123` in the options and saves it, i want that in his `code.js` the code changes from

```
(function(){var win=window.open('https://my-test-tool.com?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href )+'&k=<API-KEY>','_blank');win.focus();})()
```

to

```
(function(){var win=window.open('https://my-test-tool.com?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href )+'&k=123','_blank');win.focus();})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the new tab directly from your background script:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
  if (!tab.url) return;
  chrome.storage.sync.get('savedApi', ({savedApi}) => {
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: `https://my-test-tool.com?url=${encodeURIComponent(tab.url)}&k=${savedApi}`,
      index: tab.index + 1,
      openerTabId: tab.id,
    });
  });
});
```

To open a separate window and control its size/position you can use [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create).

Comment: Thank you! Working like a charm! I have in th code.js another code too - your snippet works with all of them, simply great!